# Closed form of an integral that seems "alike" the Laplace integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, contour-integration, closed-form

It is well-known that the Laplace integrals

> $$
> \int_0^{+\infty} \frac {\cos (ax)}{b^2 + x^2} \mathrm dx, \quad \int_0^{+\infty} \frac {x\sin (ax)}{b^2 + x^2} \mathrm dx
> $$

are computable to get a closed form via various kinds of methods [diff. wrt. parameters, contour integration, etc.]. What if we "shift" the "center" of the denominators? For example, could we get a closed form of
$$
\int_0^{+\infty} \frac {\cos (ax)}{x^2 + x+1} \mathrm dx 
$$
for $a > 0$? Thanks in advance. Any references, comments and solutions are appreciated

Comment: Mathematica gives a result for the indefinite integral, only when $\cos(ax)$ is converted to the exponential form, then struggles severely when applying the limits.

Comment: Have you tried partial fraction decomposition on the denominator?

Answer (score 1):

$$(x^2+x+1)=(x+\frac 12)^2+\frac 34$$
and so:
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(ax)}{x^2+x+1}dx=\int_{1/2}^\infty\frac{\cos\left[a(u-\frac 12)\right]}{u^2+(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^2}du$$
this lower limit is what causes the problems

Comment: Yes, I was aware the same thing.

Comment: even using double angle formula to simplify the top nicely I think this will always be an issue. I would just try writing it as $$\int_0^\infty-\int_0^{1/2}$$ then see if you can make a substitution e.g. $t=1/x$ to get infinity as an upper limit somehow but this wouldnt give you a nice integral to solve either @xbh